# Julia random number generators not working

Tags: julia

New to Julia, trying to just run this example

http://timsalimans.com/gibbs-sampling-with-julia/

but I cannot use the functions "randg" as it says it is not defined. Am I missing something?

Comment: it says it should be built in to julia. I got the latest version and no go

Comment: I upgraded comment to answer for the points (and ease for future visitors of consuming the information).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I pieced together information from http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2012/06/21/the-great-julia-rng-refactor/ and http://www.cita.utoronto.ca/~nolta/julia/pygments/monokai/deprecated.jl.html.

randg() is deprecated.  You need to use the rand() function on a Gamma object from the Distributions package.